# Using Post Sharp with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, custom-attributes, postsharp

I have created a Permission Attribute and used it in my methods written in my BLL. It works fine and debug well if i need to. But when i used the same attribute in my `WCF layer` it simply **stops working**. Not giving any error but permissions has not been checked and no debugging. Code is just ignoring the attribute.

To make things simple i use this approach

My WCF methods calls another methods defined in the same class as the WCF methods and that child method calls the BLL and this child method has the Permission Attribute on it.

But no use. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostSharp is part of the build process. I suspect the library which contains your WCF services don't run the PostSharp post-compilation process which interweaves the attribute code with your own. If it doesn't your breakpoints...etc. for the PostSharp code will not work.

Usually the post-compilation process is done by a background application that resides in the system tray on your development PC. It can be disabled however. I don't know how you are compiling the WCF service libraries.

You can manually add PostSharp to your project:

- [Adding PostSharp to your project manually](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/41129237-a5d4-4acf-aef4-c46759ccfb4b.htm#manually)

To quote the PostSharp documentation:

1. Open the project file (csproj, vbproj, ...)  using a text editor. If your project is loaded in Visual Studio, open the Solution Explorer, right-click on the project name, click on Unload project, then right-click again on the same project and click on Edit.
2. Locate the  elements near to the end of the file. For instance, a C# 2.0 project should end with an element similar to this:

   <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
3. **Before** the import line, insert the following text:

   <PropertyGroup><DontImportPostSharp>True</DontImportPostSharp></PropertyGroup>
4. **After** the C# / VB import line, insert the following text:

   <Import Project="....\Third Party\PostSharp 2.0\PostSharp.targets" />
5. Save the file and reload the project.
6. Compile.

If you are are calling methods from your BLL assemblies please check if the PostSharp post-compilation process is also run correctly.

Comment: Big Thanks for such detailed steps.

Comment: Thanks for this good answer. Note that this is now done automatically if you're using NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PostSharp but:

My first step would be to reflector the PostSharp woven IL to see what code is generated. Does it look right?

I assume that the aspect looks at some security context info. Do you have guard code in the aspect that ignores processing if the context is not valid? Does the Persmission attribute handle this without telling you.

In other words is the Permission attribute designed to work with the WCF request endpoint?